# Error: No tag "iterator" defined in tag library imported with prefix "logic"

Tags: java, jsp, struts, taglib

```
Error: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /ArrayList.jsp(9,2) No tag "iterator" defined in tag library imported with prefix "logic"
    org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
```

Here I have include my Web.xml file.

```xml
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-Param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-Param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-html
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
<taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Besides the obvious "you're not using the right tag", you really shouldn't need to be defining your taglibs in web.xml unless you're using pretty ancient tech.

Answer (score 1):

In the tld defined by the URL `http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic` there's no tag `iterator`. There's `iterate` tag name. If you are using custom tld you should specify a different URI in taglib tag and in tld file.

```xml
<taglib>
     <taglib-uri>
      /tags-logic
     </taglib-uri>
     <taglib-location>
      /WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld
     </taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

In the JSP use import

```xml
<%@ taglib uri="/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
```